# Linq Group By while avoiding Div/0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have a model, where I'm trying to calculate the weighted average:

```
  public class ObScore
  {
    public int ObScoreId { get; set; }
    public int AnalystId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int PossScore { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
  }
```

I can do this, using the following code:

```
    //
    // GET: /Test/

    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        var scores = db.ObScores.ToList();

        double weightedValueSum = scores.Sum(x=>x.PossScore * x.Weight);
        double weightSum = scores.Sum(x => x.Weight);

        if (weightSum != 0)
        {
            ViewBag.wa2 = weightedValueSum / weightSum;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

However, I want to be able to add a GroupBy clause, so I can group by Date/AnalystId etc.

Is it possible to combine the two LINQ statements, so that I can do this, while still avoiding a DIV/0 should the weightSum = 0?

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an expression like:

```
div = weightSum != 0 ? weightedValueSum / weightSum : -1
```

In the end it should be something like:

```
var res = scores.GroupBy(p => p.Date.Year)
                .Select(p => new { 
                    Year = p.Key,
                    weightedValueSum = p.Sum(x => x.PossScore * x.Weight), 
                    weightSum = p.Sum(x => x.Weight) 
                })
                .Select(p => new {
                    Year = p.Year,
                    wa2 = p.weightSum != 0 ? p.weightedValueSum / p.weightSum : -1
                })
                .ToArray();
```

That should be more or less equivalent to this in full LINQ syntax

```
var res2 = (from p in scores
            group p by p.Date.Year into p
            let Year = p.Key
            let weightedValueSum = p.Sum(x => x.PossScore * x.Weight)
            let weightSum = p.Sum(x => x.Weight)
            select new {
                Year = Year,
                wa2 = weightSum != 0 ? weightedValueSum / weightSum : -1
            }).ToArray();
```